# Proper syntax for simple conditional bloginfo language

Tags: conditional-content, multi-language, bloginfo

I need to do something like this:

```
<?php $bloginfo = get_bloginfo( 'language' );
  if($bloginfo->en-US){
     the_time('jS F Y');
  }else{ the_time('d/m/Y');
  };
 ?>
```

I cant find the proper way to wrap en-US.
Any ideas? Thank you in advance, people.

Answer (score 3):

`get_bloginfo` returns strings so this works fine:

```
<?php 
$language = get_bloginfo( 'language' );
if(language == 'en-US')
    the_time('jS F Y');
else
    the_time('d/m/Y');
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, Bainternet.(:D -1 question, im such a noob). By the way, I had to add $ to the var on the if statement to make it work (of course u know it). Thx again.