# How to retrieve blog language without any region (locale) attached?

Tags: seo, localization, language, bloginfo

How can you retrieve the language of a WordPress website, without the added region suffix attached to it? In other words, just get the language, without the entire locale.

E.g. `<html lang="en">` instead of `<html lang="en-US">`

I saw a [related question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168362/should-i-use-language-attributes-or-bloginfolanguage-in-html-tag) but it doesn't provide the exact solution, both of these are same:

- `<html <?php language_attributes();?>>`
- `<html lang="<?php bloginfo("language"); ?>">`

The reason I'm wondering this is for theming purposes, because I have noticed (after much testing) negative SEO impact on some websites that specify the region instead of just the language. Google [has claimed](https://www.woorank.com/en/edu/seo-guides/best-practices-for-language-declaration) repeatedly that this shouldn't be the case, and that they practically ignore the `<html lang="en-US">` type of flags, but I have concluded this simply isn't true after reviewing lots of SERPs from various global locations, and would like to allow our WordPress theme users to simply have the language specified without the region.

I know this can be done with some PHP magic, but I'm wondering if any existing function?

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119495/how-do-i-change-the-value-of-lang-en-us

Comment: Just so you're aware, this is not something a _theme_ has any business modifying, and doing something like this would almost certainly not be allowed by the theme repository. This type of thing, regardless of its effectiveness, would belong in a plugin and be done using a filter, such as [language_attributes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/language_attributes/) or [bloginfo](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/bloginfo/), rather than modifying the template file.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I appreciate your opinion, but I disagree, and I also don't care about WordPress.org or Automattic, as I'm banned from their community.

Comment: This is ill advised since the "region" has realworld consequences, e.g. spanish in Mexico is not the same as spanish in Spain and requires real changes to be made. There are also a lot of language codes that don't have 2 letter variants, or for which the regions indicate completely different language.

Comment: Hmm I see what you mean @TomJNowell seems WP Core doesn't follow ISO standards. It would probably require some PHP conversion to ISO 2-letter standards regardless in that case.

Comment: even then it wouldn't work how you think it works, this will be very bad for translation and accessibility, especially the automated kind that google itself does, this is a very bad idea

Comment: Worse than `art_xpirate` "Pirate English" language in WP Core? What do accessibility apps do with these non-standard codes currently? All I know is it hurts SEO greatly in many cases, so I will explore possible solutions.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47742/proper-syntax-for-simple-conditional-bloginfo-language

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this at the request of one of our Discord users, who doesn't use WPSE:

> Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange is kind of a bizarre place.  Why is
> that question voted "-2"? The question is basically asking more or
> less the same thing that multiple WordPress tickets are asking for:
>
> https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/48152
>
> https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/50183
>
> Also the W3C itself seems to recommend the same thing (avoiding the
> region in most cases):
>
> https://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/
>
> https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-choosing-language-tags
>
> But somehow the question offended the WordPress techbros, so it got
> voted -2
>
> To answer the question: WordPress does sort of have a way of getting
> this, but it's awfully obscure:
>
> https://api.wordpress.org/translations/core/1.0/
>
> If you pretty-print that, the entries look like this:
>
> ```
> {
>     "language": "en_GB",
>     "version": "6.4.1",
>     "updated": "2023-11-24 12:26:36",
>     "english_name": "English (UK)",
>     "native_name": "English (UK)",
>     "package": "https://downloads.wordpress.org/translation/core/6.4.1/en_GB.zip",
>     "iso": {
>         "1": "en",
>         "2": "eng",
>         "3": "eng"
>     },
>     "strings": {
>         "continue": "Continue"
>     }
> },
> ```
>
> The "iso" property contains the 2-letter and/or 3-letter language
> codes, without any region code.  (I'm not sure why "eng" is there
> twice.) WordPress itself uses this for the lang="..." attribute in the
> language dropdown on the page wp-admin/options-general.php Also
> "en_US" is a special case (since it has no translation) and is just
> hard-coded as lang="en":
>
> https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.4.1/wp-includes/l10n.php#L1616